# Trying to make a code where it returns you a different answer based on what name you give it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to write a program where it returns you different answers based on what name you feed it.

However it always ended up returning the same standard answer (the 'if' print) even when I gave it a different name.

What am I doing wrong?

```py
n = str(input('What's your name?')).title().strip()
name = n.split()
if name[0] == 'Jan' or 'Janet':
    print(' {} !!!'.format(name[0]))
elif name[0] == 'Kevin' or 'Darryl':
    print('...\n {} !!!'.format(name[0]))
elif name[0] == 'Mike':
    print(' {} !!!'.format(name[0]))
elif name[0] == 'James' or 'Jim' or 'Jimothy':
    print('')
else:
    print(' {} !!!'.format(nome[0]))
```

Comment: Actually it should end up with error?

Comment: `... == ... or ...` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: No, it fixed the problem. Thanks, it will help me with future codelines.